# Dojo is not defined error

Tags: dojo

Complete script:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<script src="dojo1.7/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log(dojo);    
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

The location `dojo1.7/dojo/dojo.js` is correct(checked on firebug). The error now I am getting is

```
ReferenceError: dojo is not defined
console.log(dojo)
```

So what do I missed here?

Comment: Did you try using Google hosted library URL ?

Comment: I am using dojo 1.7 downloaded folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the `console.log(dojo);` script block below the actual script. Now you're actually looking for dojo at the moment it isn't there yet.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="dojo1.7/dojo/dojo.js" data-dojo-config="async: true, parseOnLoad: true"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            console.log(dojo);    
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: That doesn't work even we first run the script and then `console.log(dojo)` on firebug

Comment: Can you try to add `type="text/javascript"`to the Dojo script?

Comment: It don't. I tried `require(["dojo/parser"]);
console.log(dojo)` on console and it's working now.

Comment: O, that's because of the `async: true` property. It allows to load the Dojo loader asynchronous.

Answer (score 4):

1. [Use a doctype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctype#HTML5_DTD-less_DOCTYPE).
2. Scripts are loaded and executed in the order they are defined in HTML, so scripts that define objects need to be placed *before* the script that uses the object.
3. A global `dojo` object is never defined when you are running in async mode. You need to use the global `require` function to explicitly load dependencies:

```js
require([ 'dojo/dom', 'dojo/on' ], function (dom, on) {
    // code here
});
```